# How to delete all non-numerical letters in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have some data in DATA column (varchar) that looks like this:

```
Nowshak 7,485 m
Maja e Korabit (Golem Korab) 2,764 m
Tahat 3,003 m
Morro de Moco 2,620 m
Cerro Aconcagua 6,960 m (located in the northwestern corner of the province of Mendoza)
Mount Kosciuszko 2,229 m
Grossglockner 3,798 m
```

What I want is this:

```
7485
2764
3003
2620
6960
2229
3798
```

**Is there a way in IBM DB2 version 9.5 to remove/delete all those non-numeric letters by doing something like this:**

```
SELECT replace(DATA, --somekind of regular expression--, '') FROM TABLE_A
```

**or any other ways?**

This question follows from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596166/how-to-extract-numerical-data-from-sql-result).

Comment: for the record, on DB2 11.1, you could simply do this `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(data,'[^0-9]','') FROM TABLE_A`

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the other question, the [TRANSLATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000862.htm) function might help. For example, try this:

```
select translate('Nowshak 7,485 m','','Nowshakm,') from sysibm.sysdummy1;
```

Returns:

```
7 485
```

Probably with a little tweaking you can get it to how you want it...in the third argument of the function you just need to specify the entire alphabet.  Kind of ugly but it will work.

Comment: And then you can use [REPLACE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000843.htm) to strip out the white spaces, if you want to:`select replace(translate('Nowshak 7,485 m','','Nowshakm,'),' ','') from sysibm.sysdummy1`

Comment: Actually, if he uses an _empty_ string as the replacement, he doesn't need to do a second round.

Comment: For some reason when I use TRANSLATE with an empty replacement string I get the error : Argument 02 of function TRANSLATE not valid. So I need to use also REPLACE

Answer (score 5):

One easy way to accomplish that is to use the TRANSLATE(value, replacewith, replacelist) function.  It replaces all of the characters in a list (third parameter) with the value in the second parameter.

You can leverage that to essentially erase all of the non-numeric charaters out of the character string, including the spaces.

Just make the list in the third parameter contain all of the possible characters you might see that you don't want. Translate those to an empty space, and you end up with just the characters you want, essentially erasing the undesired characters.

Note: I included all of the common symbols (non-alpha numeric) for the benefit of others who may have character values of a larger variety than your example.

```
Select 
   TRANSLATE(UCASE(CHAR_COLUMN),'',
            'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()-=+/\{}[];:.,<>? ')
FROM TABLE_A
```

More simply: For your particular set of values, since there is a much smaller set of possible characters you could trim the replace list down to this:

```
Select 
   TRANSLATE(UCASE(CHAR_COLUMN),'','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ(), ')
FROM TABLE_A
```

NOTE:  The "UCASE" on the CHAR_COLUMN is not necessary, but it was a nice enhancement to simplify this expression by eliminating the need to include all of the lower case alpha characters.

```
TRANSLATE(CHAR_COLUMN,'',
      'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-=+/\{}[];:.,<>? ')
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as an existing answer (you just listed all relevant characters).  What else could you do to make yours more differentiable?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback C-M.  I added some detail. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: You should have UCASE then you don't need the lower case letters.

Comment: I like that, @Hogan!  I'll add that to the answer. That works since it will not affect our target characters, but keep in mind that if this was used to isolate alpha chars, you wouldn't want to UCASE the incoming character string.

Answer (score 5):

As many of the answers above your best approach is to use the TRANSLATE function.  However this approach is a different as you can white list the characters you want instead of black list the characters you don't want.  We can do this by using the TRANSLATE function twice.  We'll use the inner translate to generate a list of characters to remove for the parameter of the outer translate.

```
select TRANSLATE(dirty,'',TRANSLATE(dirty,'','1234567890',''),'') as clean
from (Values 'Nowshak 7,485 m'
             ,'Maja e Korabit (Golem Korab) 2,764 m'
             ,'Tahat 3,003 m','Morro de Moco 2,620 m'
             ,'Cerro Aconcagua 6,960 m (located in the northwestern corner of the province of Mendoza)'
             ,'Mount Kosciuszko 2,229 m','Grossglockner 3,798 m'
      ) as temp(dirty)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just taking @Darryls99 and turning it into a UDF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REMOVE_ALLBUT(in_string VARCHAR(32000), characters_to_remote VARCHAR(32000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(32000)
LANGUAGE SQL CONTAINS SQL DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
RETURN
TRANSLATE(in_string,'',TRANSLATE(in_string,'',characters_to_remote,''),'')
;
```

use like this

```
select DB_REMOVE_ALLBUT(s,'1234567890')
from (values 'Nowshak 7,485 m'
             ,'Maja e Korabit (Golem Korab) 2,764 m'
             ,'Tahat 3,003 m','Morro de Moco 2,620 m'
             ,'Cerro Aconcagua 6,960 m (located in the northwestern corner of the province of Mendoza)'
             ,'Mount Kosciuszko 2,229 m'
             ,'Grossglockner 3,798 m'
      ) t(s);
```

which returns

```
 1
 ----
 7485
 2764
 3003
 2620
 6960
 2229
 3798
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty string can be like this: *'qwerty12453lala<<>777*9'*

We need to get cleared  string and keep only digits.

We could remove any excess characters with TRANSLATE function,
but there is one problem: too long and ugly value of 3-th parameter.
Something like this:

```
VALUES
(
TRANSLATE( UPPER('qwerty12453lala<<>777*9'), '', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()-=+/\{}[];:.,<>? ')
)
```

So, this is not very convenient.

My idea is - use TRANSLATE functuion 2 times ( one time inside another one):

- Calculate 3-th parameter as a particular list of replaced symbols
- Use TRANSLATE function second time to replace excess symbols by using this calculated parameter

Let me show you here in code:

```
VALUES
( 
  REPLACE --Remove spaces from result
  (  
    TRANSLATE
    (
      UPPER( 'qwerty12453lala<<>777*9')
    , ' '
    , TRANSLATE( UPPER( 'qwerty12453lala<<>777*9') , ' ' , '0123456789')-- This is calculation of 3-th param, it contains only NOT digital characters, like 'QWERTYLALA<<>*'
    )
  , ' '
  , ''  
  )  
)
```

Result must be like this: *124537779*

In case SELECT statement, it would be like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE
       (
         TRANSLATE( UPPER(T.DIRTY_FIELD), ' ', TRANSLATE(UPPER(T.DIRTY_FIELD), '', '1234567890' ) )
       , ' '
       , ''
       )
  FROM SOMETABLE T
```

Answer (score 0):

the proper combination of all

`select  replace(translate(dirty,' ','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-=+/{}[];:.,<>?' ), ' ','') as clean`

Answer (score 0):

with spec_char (col1, col2, Col3) as (
select Veh_Desc, Lic_plate, TRANSLATE(Lic_plate,'9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890') as clean_data
from YourTableName)
select * from spec_char where col3 <> '99999999'

This will give you vehicles with license plate containing special char, i.e other than A-Z and 0-9.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way in IBM DB2 version 9.5
>   to remove/delete all those non-numeric
>   letters by doing something like this:
>
> SELECT replace(DATA, --somekind of
>   regular expression--, '') FROM TABLE_A
>
> or any other ways?

No. You will have to create a [User Defined Function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsadhelp/v5r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.subuilder.doc/topics/cudf.html) or implement it in your host application's language.

Answer (score -1):

The statement below will remove non-alphanumeric characters from any 'string-value' and prevents the SQLSTATE message 42815 when a zero length string-value is passed.

```
SELECT REPLACE(TRANSLATE(string-value || '|',
                        '||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||',
                        '`¬!"£$%^&*()_-+={[}]:;@~#,<>.?/'''),'|','')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```