# Stripping out non-digits - SQL0171 Argument of function TRANSLATE not valid

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to extract the first ten digit numbers of a phone number, ending up with a 10-digit (or less) number.
I need to use whitelisting, not blacklisting, due to special characters having been used. e.g. "á(123) 555-4567 Toll Free:á(891) 0" must become 1235554567.

I'm trying to use https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685384.

However, when I try to use this:

```
TRANSLATE(SFCONTACT.PHONE,'',TRANSLATE(SFCONTACT.PHONE,'','1234567890',''),'') as clean
```

I get

> Message: [SQL0171] Argument 04 of function TRANSLATE not valid.

One of the comments said that using spaces instead of empty strings removed that. However, for me, trying:

```
TRANSLATE(SFCONTACT.PHONE,' ',TRANSLATE(SFCONTACT.PHONE,' ','1234567890',' '),' ') as clean
```

gives:

> Message: [SQL0171] Argument 03 of function TRANSLATE not valid.

How can I accomplish this?

Running an AS400 DB2, IBM version V7R1M0

**EDIT** (Not sure if this should be a separate Question or not)

I tried this as suggested:

```
SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE, '[\D]', ''),1,10) AS MAINPHONE,
```

And at first it seemed to work; I was able to create a view, BBICNTMIG

However, when I try to insert into a table using that view:

```
INSERT INTO AMMLIBC.BBICONTACT
(COMPANY,CUSNO,SHIPTO,HONORIFICFK,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,MAINPHONE,TYPEFK,PROSPECTFK,CREATEDBY,CREATEDAT)
SELECT COMPANY,CUSNO,SHIPTO,HONORIFICFK,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,MAINPHONE,TYPEFK,PROSPECTFK,CREATEDBY,CREATEDAT
FROM AMMLIBC.BBICNTMIG
```

it gives:

> Message: [SQL0420] Character in CAST argument not valid. Cause . . . . . :   A character in the argument for the CAST function was not correct. Recovery  . . . :   Change the result data type to one that recognizes the characters in the CAST argument, or change the argument to contain a valid representation of a value for the result data type. Try the request again.

If I remove the phone numbers from the insert (taking default value of null instead), then the INSERT succeeds, so I know it's the phone number causing this.

The column type in the destination table is NUMERIC(10,0). I tried using this, but no change:

```
CAST(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE, '[\D]', ''),1,10) AS NUMERIC(10,0)) AS MAINPHONE,
```

Further info:

I tried casting to char before casting to numeric. No change.

I tried adding a where clause (both "mainphone is null" and "mainphone is not null" do this) and the error message changes to:

> Message: [SQL0802] Data conversion or data mapping error. Cause . . . . . :   Error type 6 has occurred. [...] 6 -- Numeric data that is not valid.

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: `\D` is the same as `^\d` One of the few places where case actually matters on an iseries. Put it as a lowercase 'd'.

Comment: ...Derp. Right, because it's a Regex. Fixing that didn't fix the issue, though.

Comment: Casting the char string to EBCDIC first fixed it for me. `cast(cast(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE, '[\D]', ''),1,10) as char(10) CCSID 37) as numeric(10,0))`

Comment: `\d` matches all Unicode characters in class  `Number, Decimal Digit`  which does include Arabic numbers such as. `٦` UU+0666 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT SIX  which Db2 won't cast to an INTEGER.  So `[0-9]` in the regex is less vunerable if the source data is free-form input from an uncontrolled source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "FETCH FIRST _ ROWS ONLY" and binary search, I found the problem.

The phone number it was trying to parse was "PLEASE VERIFY CONTACT AND EMAIL". Which, stripping out digits, turns into empty string... which does not convert well into NUMERIC(10,0).

So, this fixed the problem:

```
CASE
    WHEN TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE, '[\D]', '')) = '' THEN NULL
    ELSE CAST(SUBSTR(REGEXP_REPLACE(PHONE, '[\D]', ''),1,10) AS NUMERIC(10,0))
END AS MAINPHONE,
```

Answer (score 2):

The `TRANSLATE` function doesn't work correctly for non-ascii characters.
Use the following instead:

```
SELECT substr(
--  xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:replace($s, "[^\d]", "")' passing PHONE  as "s") as varchar(4000)) -- DB2 for LUW
regexp_replace(PHONE, '[^\d]', '') -- DB2 for LUW 11.1 & DB2 for IBM i
, 1, 10)
FROM TABLE(VALUES 
  'á(123) 555-4567 Toll Free:á(891) 0'
, 'á(123) 555-'
) SFCONTACT(PHONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Platform & version of Db2 is important...

Db2 for i 7.2, for instance, gives me

> Cause . . . . . :   Parameter 3 specified in function TRANSLATE is not valid for use for reason code 1. The reason codes and their meanings follow:
>        1 -- Parameter must be a string constant.
>        2 -- Parameter must be an integer constant.
>        3 -- Parameter must be a numeric constant.
>        4 -- Parameter's length is too long.
>        5 -- Parameter's value is out of range.
>        6 -- Parameter must be a valid CCSID.
>        7 -- Parameter cannot be a parameter marker.
>        8 -- Parameter's data type is not supported by the built-in function.
>        9 -- Parameter cannot reference a column with an active column mask since the function is not secured.
>    Recovery  . . . :   Refer to the DB2 for IBM i SQL Reference topic collection in the Database category in the IBM i Information Center book, http://www.ibm.com/systems/i/infocenter/ for more information on functions. Correct the parameter specified for the function. Try the request again.